# fatal error: #include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp" no such file or directory

Tags: c++

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS 2 Iron Irwini, I have been able to run the tutorials, but when I run a ultrasonic ranger program I get fatal error `#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp" no such file or directory`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(ultrasonic_ranger)
#default to c++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()
add_executable(ultrasonic_ranger src/ultrasonic_ranger.cpp)

target_link_libraries(ultrasonic_ranger ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(ultrasonic_ranger ${rclcpp_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(ultrasonic_ranger PUBLIC ${rclcpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)


if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

Comment: thank you it was my CMakeLists.txt I move my find_package and deleted my third target_link_library and it solved my problem build was successful.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

Looking at the content of `CMakeLists.txt`, you are using the `find_package` command after calling `add_executable`. This is why the compiler can not find ROS header files. Please move all `find_package` commands above.

I suggest looking at the official repository, such as [CMakeLists.txt.](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/cbeb3135f932dc6297d3e8675912b2209270e796/rclcpp/topics/minimal_publisher/CMakeLists.txt)